# Want to create a xml annotation files in VOC format using existing data from text annotation file. But cant do anything with the text within head

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

pls help me to create an xml as follows,

```
<annotation verified="yes">
<folder>images</folder>
<filename>ss    </filename>
<path>/Users/datitran/Desktop/raccoon/images/raccoon-1.jpg</path>
<source>
<database>Unknown</database>
</source>
</annotation>
```

I could manage to get this given part. check the annotation in the above xml.

```
<annotation>
<folder>images</folder>
<filename>raccoon-1.jpg</filename>
<path>
/**/raccoon/images/raccoon-1.jpg
</path>
</annotation>
```

can you help me with the verified="yes" in annotation part?
my code goes like this.

```
self.root = ET.Element("annotation").
folder = ET.SubElement(self.root, "folder").text='images'
filename = ET.SubElement(self.root, "filename").text='raccoon-1.jpg'
path = ET.SubElement(self.root, "path").text='/**/raccoon/images/raccoon-1.jpg'</i>
```

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element

root = Element("annotation", verified='yes')

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

#output:

```
<annotation verified="yes" />
```

---

Another method you can use is `set`[Python xml etree doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set) :

```
root = Element("annotation")
attr  = "verified"
value = "yes"
root.set(attr, value)
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

#output:

```
<annotation verified="yes" />
```